# ElasticSearch query hangs in laravel job queue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, elasticsearch

I am currently using the [laravel-elasticsearch](https://github.com/shift31/laravel-elasticsearch) provider for my ES queries. I am using this from within a job that is processed by my laravel queue(using beanstalkd). The problem I am having is that in long running jobs, eventually I am no longer able to insert data into elasticsearch. The job just hangs (no exceptions are thrown) I have narrowed it down to the code where I am making an ES call. Is it possible that my connection could become stale some how and not reconnect? my other thought is that it has something to do with using a Facade and it being a singleton.

here is what I am doing, this is not my exact code. but the code works just fine when it is not run in a long running job.I just wanted to provide some context.it inserts just fine, there are no issues with the code functioning until it is run after a long running process.

**UPDATE:**

I have narrowed the issue down to the elasticsearch-php library persisting a connection. I have my ES behind a load balancer that times out TCP connections after 5 min. the issue is that there is no keep alive in the ES php library. after 5 min the connection is closed but it does not close the connection on my end. is there a way to set a keep alive for elasticsearch-php? or a call to reset the connection?

```
//run some functions....
$params = array();
$params['body']  = array('somefield' => 'some data');
$params['index'] = 'my_index';
$params['type']  = 'my_type';
$params['id']    = 'my_id';
$ret = Es::update($params);//this is working just fine

//long running function here
$newparams = array();
$newparams['body']  = array('somefield' => 'some data');
$newparams['index'] = 'my_index';
$newparams['type']  = 'my_type';
$newparams['id']    = 'my_id';
$return = Es::update($newparams);//this will just hang
```

Comment: looks like problem with job failing rather than with ES. are you handling failed jobs?

Comment: I am handling failing jobs, but the job does not fail it just hangs as if it is trying to connect to ES without a timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing to fix this issue was add the following setting when creating the ES client.

```
'guzzleOptions' => array(
              'curl.options' => [
                  CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => true
              ]
          ),
```

hope this helps someone out.

Comment: I know it's an oldie, but  you!

Answer (score 5):

Gather around, and let's talk about long lasting queue processes.

Laravel queues work, with workers. Those rentless elves fetch the jobs from our queue service and processes them in a timely fashion.

However, after long periods of incessant work, our elves start to get tired and create errors randomly. Types of errors include failure [to send mail using `SwiftMailer`](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/490), to process database transactions or [connect to SSL ports](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4573).

What our elves need, is an energy drink, in the form of `queue:restart`, every 20 mins.

**Steps to implement:**

1) If you are on linux, type in console `sudo crontab -e`

2) Using vim, enter the following lines `0,20,40 * * * * cd /path/to/my/laravel/installation && php artisan queue:restart --env=yourenvironment 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

Replace `/path/to/my/laravel/installation` with your laravel's path.

And `yourenvironment` with your laravel's environment name.

Source: I have an elasticsearch installation with uptime of one month, and laravel polling and updating data in real-time using the shift31's package.

Documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#daemon-queue-worker

Comment: Won't restarting the queue kill the current job that is processing ?

Comment: I have tried restarting the queue, no luck though. please take a look at my update above.

Comment: Restarting a queue will wait till the currently processing job is complete. Hence no data loss.

Comment: If your load balancer is closing connections every 5 mins (which is quite low), i suggest that you set the cron job to execute every 2 mins. Note that this may spike your CPU usage on your VM.

Comment: Alternatively, you can simply close the connection used by Guzzle in Elasticsearch after a request. See `vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection.php`. Line 165. Add: `$request->setHeader('Connection', 'Close');` Source: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/113